# SQL Query performance test

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to check the performance of my SQL query but every time I execute the same query I am getting different execution time due to cache and statistics.

I tried to use the following commands before every cycle but the problem persists:

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
```

Comment: How different are the results?  It's going to depend on what else SQL Server is doing.

Comment: Try "SET STATISTICS IO ON" before you run your query.  It's not perfect, but it is one among multiple ways to compare query performance, specifically physical and logical page reads.  It's consistent from one execution to the next and, usually, fewer reads are better.

Comment: To expand on Kevin's point.  Unless your database files are on dedicated storage, you are likely competing for resources.  Your query will take longer when other people.  SET STATISTICS IO ON helps you compare apples to apples.